# Mono - Corlib not in sync with this runtime

Tags: mono

I am trying to get Sonarr running on my xubuntu server as it is the last thing i need to move to decommission my windows server. I've gotten emby running with mono without issue, but I'm getting this error when trying to run sonarr:

Corlib not in sync with this runtime: expected corlib version 111, found 138.
Loaded from: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll
Download a newer corlib or a newer runtime at http://www.go-mono.com/daily.

I've tried updating my packages with the mono main channels, then beta channels, then the alpha channels and continue to receive this exact problem. go-mono.com/daily doesn't resolve in my browser.

Any answer's I've found on forums for this issue seem to just say to get the thing straight from the mono repos to cure the issue, which I did from the beginning.

If this helps at all, before this issue I had the mscorlib not found error, because there was no /usr/local/lib/mono or wherever it is suppose to be and I had to symlink /usr/local/mono i think (not sure on those paths exactly, my brain is about fried at this point.) This is on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS

Can anyone point me in the right direction?